# vbscript simple send key not working

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

i have a simple vbscript that perform "Ctrl 2", the sendkey work perfectly in my PC, when i try it in another PC it's not working at all.

here is the code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.SendKeys "^2"
```

tried to add parentheses and also i changed the UAC the the lowest but till not working.
i would like to add that the other PC is in French language if that can be the problem.

thank guys

Comment: What about  running `WshShell.Run "%windir%\notepad.exe"`and activating `WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"` an app before sending keys?

Comment: unfortunately it's not working, the code work on my PC but on other one no, is there any thing that can prevent sendkey not work on windows 7